# How can i set already migrated migrations as a migrated migrations in Laravel without migrate:fresh?

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

I have 20 tables in my database. and i want to migrate a new one into the database. 
But i get the error :

> Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'house_statuses' already
>   exists.

This table is already in database but everytime i want to migrate something new i got this while this migration already has been migrated earlier.

I see some solutions like yeah `Migrate:fresh`, 
But i dont want to remove my records in database because its so much work to set the records back

Comment: Why dont you create a new migration?

Comment: What do that make a diffrence? i

Comment: Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert more columns in your table you should use the `Schema::table`, for example:

Let's say you need one more column in your `users` table, you can simply do that:

Use the command:

```
php artisan make:migration add_age_to_users_table --table=users
```

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('age');
});
```

And then use:

```
php artisan migrate
```

This way your `users` table will be updated with the new column `age`

Everytime you want to make a change in your Database you should **create a new migration and not edit the last one**.

Answer (score 0):

Follow following steps:

1. Find the file name where you have mentioned to create this table.
2. Copy file name
3. Insert file name to migrations table.

It might help you.

Comment: Its already in the migrations table. and i removed it and added it back and still not working